# Retaining color when subsampling a triangulated surface: get indices from reducepatch?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, triangulation

I have a very densely tessellated surface which looks like this:
[image: White matter dense]

This surface is too densely tessellated for me, so I subsample it to get a coarser surface. To do this, I used Matlab's [`reducepatch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reducepatch.html) function. This works pretty well:
[image: White matter subsampled]

Unfortunately, the coloring is based on a variable called `sulcal_depth`, which is defined for every vertex of my tessellated surface. So I need to retain sulcal depth information only from the vertices which remain after subsampling. Essentially, I need `reducepatch` to give me not just the subsampled version of the surface, but also the *indices of vertex points that it retained*. If I know the preserved indices, I can just index my `sulcal_depth` variable to get the new depth map.

Currently, I'm doing this as follows (this is also how I colored the subsampled version above):

```
function indices = compute_reduced_indices(before, after)
%% Function to compute the indices of vertices preserved during an operation of
%  reducepatch. This allows you to use reducepatch to subsample a surface and
%  re-compute an original signal on the vertices for the new subsampled mesh

indices = zeros(length(after), 1);
for i = 1:length(after)
    dotprods = (before * after(i, :)') ./ sqrt(sum(before.^2, 2));
    [~, indices(i)] = max(dotprods);
end
```

But as you might imagine, this is pretty slow, because of the for loop over vertices. I don't have enough memory to vectorize the loop and compute the full dot product matrix in one go.

Is there a smart way to get `reducepatch` to give me indices, or an alternative approach (with or without `reducepatch`) that's faster?

Comment: Never used this function; generally if speed is a concern, try using "run and profile" to figure out what is slowing down. Also for some case you might be able to use coder to compile as mex file. It would give much better performance most of times.

Comment: @Developer That's a fair suggestion. I'll consider this if there's no simpler alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `reducepath` only delete some vertex but doesn't change the coordinate of the preserved points you can use the function `ismember`:

```
%Load the "flow" matlab's dataset.
[x,y,z,v] = flow(100);
%Patch the isosurface
p = patch(isosurface(x,y,z,v,-3));
%Reducepatch
rp = reducepatch(p,0.15);
%Create an index of the preserved vertex.
[ind,loc] = ismember(p.Vertices,rp.vertices,'rows'); 
%Checksum
sum(find(ind) == sort(indices)) == length(indices) %should be = 1

%if you want to preserve the index order:
locb = loc(ind);
subind = find(ind);
[~,revsor] = sort(locb);
ind = subind(revsor);
```

**BENCHMARKING**

```
[x,y,z,v] = flow(100);

p = patch(isosurface(x,y,z,v,-3));
rp = reducepatch(p,0.15);
tic
ind = ismember(p.Vertices,rp.vertices,'rows');
toc

before = p.Vertices;
after = rp.vertices;

tic 
indices = zeros(length(after), 1);
for i = 1:length(after)
    dotprods = (before * after(i, :)') ./ sqrt(sum(before.^2, 2));
    [~, indices(i)] = max(dotprods);
end
toc
```

**RESULT**

```
Elapsed time is 0.196078 seconds. %ismember solution 
Elapsed time is 11.280293 seconds. %dotproduct solution
```

Comment: The checksum you've mentioned almost tells me how to get there. Since I now need to have the sulcal depths matched to the vertices, how would I "unsort" the result of `find(ind)` in order to keep the sulcal depths in the same order?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, you can index your sulcal vector with the logical index `ind` or with the "position" index `find(ind), `but here the order doesn't matter.

Comment: The order matters when I plot, for example. I need to have the sulcal depths in the same order as the subsampled vertices. In other words, ind tells me _which_ vertices were chosen by `reducepatch`, but not what order they were stored in `after`. I'm given to understand that `ismember` returns the index in a second return variable. I'm trying to see if that can be used somehow...

Comment: That did it! You're brilliant!